# Updating formula result based on checkbox set to true

Tags: formula, formula-field, error-messages

I'm working on a formula field that will display various options on a field called Option Picked based on the amount in the secondary custom field called "last month GTV" If Client type is "Customer".

Option A
Option B
Option C

```
IF( (ISPICKVAL( Type , "Customer")) ,( 


IF( Last_Month_GTV__c >160,"3. Option A", 
(IF (Last_Month_GTV__c >40, "2. Option B", 
(IF (Last_Month_GTV__c >0, "1. Option C",Null)))))), 
"Prospect")
```

that works without any issue. However, I want to add the criteria if a VIP checkbox on the same object is checked to **True** then ignore the amount and update the option to **Option A** regardless of the Last Month GTV amount.

Here is my attempt when adding OR to the formula:

```
IF( (ISPICKVAL( Type , "Customer")) ,( 


IF( Last_Month_GTV__c >160 || (IF( VIP__c = 'yes'),"3. 
Option A", 
(IF (Last_Month_GTV__c >40, "2. Option B", 
(IF (Last_Month_GTV__c >0, "1. Option C",Null))))))))),
"Prospect")
```

I keep getting the error message "Error: Syntax Error. Missing')'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible that you are missing a parenthesis somewhere as the error message states? you should try fixing that error first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkbox will not consider String `yes` for comparison, it should be either Boolean type `true` or `false` or `1` or `0`.

Use this approach.

```
IF( (ISPICKVAL( Type , "Customer")) , 
    IF(VIP__c, "3. Option A",
    ( 
    IF( Last_Month_GTV__c >160,"3. Option A", 
        (IF (Last_Month_GTV__c >40, "2. Option B", 
            (IF (Last_Month_GTV__c >0, "1. Option C",Null))
            )
        )
    )
   )
 ), 
"Prospect")
```

Comment: Just VIP__c is fine. No need to `= TRUE`.

Comment: thats also true

Comment: @SantanuBoral thank you for your help, that worked!